# Ruby Hashing - Multiple Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a Ruby array which I get from the database which looks like this when I print it :

```
<% @Aarr.each do |row1| %>
<%= row1[0] %>  :   <%= row1[1] %> :   <%= row1[2] %>
<br>
<% end %>
```

OUTPUT:

```
10.0.1.50 : 8k : IP 
10.0.1.50 : 8k : UMTS 
10.0.1.51 : 8k : IP 
10.0.1.51 : 8k : UMTS 
10.0.1.50 : 9k : IP 
10.0.1.50 : 9k : Stability 
10.0.1.50 : 9k : UMTS 
11.0.1.50 : 9k : IP 
11.0.1.50 : 9k : UMTS
```

I want to apply some kind of hashing on this such that the result should be the following:

```
10.0.1.50 : 8k : 2
10.0.1.51 : 8k : 2
10.0.1.50 : 9k : 3
11.0.1.50 : 9k : 2
```

So Basically I want the key to be the first two columns of my array.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you have a particular question, rather than "do my work for me"?

Comment: What is your current db query?

Comment: I tried using a normal hash, something like this: 

 @Arr_new = @Arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element|
 hash[element] +=1
 hash }

But it does not return my desired output

Comment: @MarkThomas : I know I can do it while querying the DB. But I want to use this array at multiple places within the application. So firing multiple queries was a bad idea than creating another array within my application.

Comment: *Thinking* something is bad is different to *knowing* it's bad. Start with whatever is easiest to program and *then* measure the performance. This looks like something a database is good at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
result = {}
@your_array.map{|row| "#{row[0]} : #{row[1]}"}.each do |key|
  result[key] = (result[key] ||= 0) + 1
end
```

I agree with your original post's user comments though, db should handle this better.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. You could use `each_with_object` to cut out the extra local if you wanted too.

Comment: @iain New to ruby, so much to learn! Thanx for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_by` to group them by the first two columns, then return the length of each group to get the output you want:

```
arr.group_by{|row| row.take(2)}.map{|k,v| [k, v.length].flatten.join " : "}
```

Output:

```
10.0.1.50 : 8k : 2
10.0.1.51 : 8k : 2
10.0.1.50 : 9k : 3
11.0.1.50 : 9k : 2
```